# How to read a state variable whose type is a union type?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

As the title suggests, how can I read a field of a state variable whose type is a union type?

More accurately, I have a defined a zustand store like so:

```js
import { create } from 'zustand'
    
type HeightUnit = 'cm' | 'ft\' in"' | null
type HeightValue = { cm: number } | { ft: number; in: number } | null

interface OnboardingStore {
  gender: { selectedButtonId: number | null; label: string }
  age: { textChange: string; textSubmit: string }
  height: {
    selectedButtonId: number | null,
    unit: HeightUnit,
    cmTextChange: string,
    ftTextChange: string,
    inTextChange: string,
    value: HeightValue
  }
  bodyWeight: { units: string; value: string }
  fitnessExperience: string

  setGender: (value: { selectedButtonId: number; label: string }) => void
  setAge: (value: { textChange: string; textSubmit: string }) => void
  setHeight: (value: {
    selectedButtonId: number | null,
    unit: HeightUnit,
    cmTextChange: string,
    ftTextChange: string,
    inTextChange: string,
    value: HeightValue,
  }) => void
  setBodyWeight: (value: { units: string; value: string }) => void
  setFitnessExperience: (value: string) => void
}

const useOnboardingStore = create<OnboardingStore>()((set) => ({
  gender: { selectedButtonId: null, label: '' },
  age: { textChange: '', textSubmit: '' },
  height: {
    selectedButtonId: null,
    unit: null,
    cmTextChange: '',
    ftTextChange: '',
    inTextChange: '',
    value: null,
  },
  bodyWeight: { units: '', value: '' },
  fitnessExperience: '',

  setGender: (value) => set({ gender: value }),
  setAge: (value) => set({ age: value }),
  setHeight: (value) => set({ height: value }),
  setBodyWeight: (value) => set({ bodyWeight: value }),
  setFitnessExperience: (value) => set({ fitnessExperience: value }),
}))
export default useOnboardingStore
```

And the type I'm interested in is value: HeightValue.

I would like to read it's value in a placeholder field like so:

```
       <Input
                    onChangeText={(text) => {
                      console.log('The feet is: ', text)
                      setHeight({ ...height, ftTextChange: text })
                    }}
                    onSubmitEditing={onSubmit}
                    // FIX: Error here
                    placeholder={height.value?.ft?.toString() ?? ''}
                    placeholderTextColor={(
                      height.ftTextChange.length > 0 ||
                      height.value !== null
                    ) ? 'primary.50' : 'secondary.50' }
                    borderColor={(
                      height.ftTextChange.length > 0 ||
                      height.value !== null
                    ) ? 'primary.50' : 'secondary.50' }
                    keyboardType='number-pad'
                    height={20}
                    width={16}
                    fontSize={20}
                    fontWeight='bold'
                    color='primary.50'
                    backgroundColor={'tertiary.300'}
                    textAlign='center'
                    _focus={{ borderColor: 'primary.50' }}
                    borderRadius={10}
                    mx={2}
                  />
```

However I get an error:

```
Property 'ft' does not exist on type '{ cm: number; } | { ft: number; in: number; }'.
Property 'ft' does not exist on type '{ cm: number; }'. [2339]
```

I tried implementing the null guard checks buy I suspect I'm doing it incorrectly. Any guidance would be super appreciated! Thanks.

Edit: Here's the full [component](https://pastecord.com/ilubonulut)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "null guard check" is not sufficient here. The issue is that in a union type, TypeScript does not know for sure that a property exists on an object, because it could be one of the possible union types that does not include that property. So, it won't let you check for null in the first place, because it can't be sure that property even exists. The absence of a property is not the same as it being `null`.

What you need instead is a "[type guard](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-use-type-guards-typescript/)". By checking for *existence* of the property, you can narrow the type sufficiently to allow TypeScript to know whether it can *access* it or not.

```
placeholder={'ft' in height.value ? height.value?.ft?.toString() ?? '' : ''}
```

Comment: That's amazing! Thank you for educating a noob, that link was very helpful as well 